# Can't create and run an Azure ML Text NER job from Python script

Tags: python, sdk, azure-machine-learning-service, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to trigger a Text NER job on Azure ML service from a Python script, with training and validation folders uploaded on the datastore from local paths. The code is as follows:

```
import os

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.ai.ml import automl, Input, MLClient
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes
from azure.ai.ml.entities import ResourceConfiguration

os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"] = <my_client_id>
os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"] = <my_tenant_id>
os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"] = <my_client_secret_id>

subscription_id = <my_subscription_id>
resource_group = <my_resource_group_id>
workspace = <my_workspace_id>

ml_client = MLClient(DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id, resource_group, workspace)

training_mltable_path = "./training-mltable-folder/"
validation_mltable_path = "./validation-mltable-folder/"

my_training_data_input = Input(type=AssetTypes.MLTABLE, path=training_mltable_path)
my_validation_data_input = Input(type=AssetTypes.MLTABLE, path=validation_mltable_path)

text_ner_job = automl.text_ner(
    name="dpv2-nlp-text-ner-job-01",
    experiment_name="dpv2-nlp-text-ner-experiment",
    training_data=my_training_data_input,
    validation_data=my_validation_data_input
)

text_ner_job.set_limits(timeout_minutes=60)
text_ner_job.resources = ResourceConfiguration(instance_type="Standard_NC6s_v3")

returned_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(
    text_ner_job
)

print(f"Created job: {returned_job}")

ml_client.jobs.stream(returned_job.name)
```

However, when I run this code, it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    raise JobException(
azure.ai.ml.exceptions.JobException: Exception : 
 {
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "Failed to validate user configuration and data.\n 1. The data file does not exists. Ensure data correctness and availability.",
        "message_parameters": {},
        "target": "ValidationService",
        "details": [
            {
                "code": "UserError",
                "severity": 2,
                "message": "The data file does not exists. Ensure data correctness and availability.",
                "message_format": "The data file does not exists. Ensure data correctness and availability.",
                "message_parameters": {
                    "0": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]"
                },
                "target": "training_data",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "message": "null",
                        "message_parameters": {},
                        "details": []
                    }
                ],
                "inner_error": {
                    "code": "BadArgument",
                    "inner_error": {
                        "code": "ArgumentInvalid",
                        "inner_error": {
                            "code": "DatasetInvalidPath"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

I'm fairly confident that the uploaded data is in the correct format for this type of task, so it can be an availability problem.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: You are right, the error message indicates that azure ml is unable to access your data. please refer to this [notebook](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/jobs/automl-standalone-jobs/automl-nlp-text-named-entity-recognition-task/automl-nlp-text-ner-task.ipynb) and check if the data is uploaded correctly.

Comment: My code is taken directly from that notebook. I've tried both loading the training data and retrieving it from the datastore, but the error persists. I can't seem to figure out why it can't access them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the input data of the type `AssetTypes.MLTABLE`. It should look like the image below.

[image]

There should be a file called `MLTable`, and inside it, the paths of the data files should be mentioned.

Check your input folders and change them as shown above.

Alternatively, you can create an MLTable type data in the data asset and use that path as shown below.

```py
my_training_data_input = Input(type=AssetTypes.MLTABLE, path="azureml://datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/my_training_mltable")

my_validation_data_input = Input(type=AssetTypes.MLTABLE, path="azureml://datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/my_validation_mltable")
```

To create a data asset:

Go to **Data** > click on **create** > select **source files** option > select **workspace blobstore** location > **upload your files** and click on create.

[image]

After creating, you will get a path like the one below. Use that path in your code.

[image]